# Removing ShipFree coupon is one product in cart matches specific category

Tags: magento2.3, coupon

First post so bare with me. We have an issue with the logic on our Shipfree coupon code. What we want is to invalidate the shipfree coupon code if any one product in the cart is assigned to a specific category. We'll call this category "over-sized items".

Right now if a customer has one item in the "over-sized items" category and one item that is not, Magento will still apply the coupon. How can we get it to invalidate the coupon based on that one item in the "over-sized items" category?

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding a [condition to the coupon’s Cart Price Rule](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/price-rules-cart-create.html#step-2-describe-the-conditions).

[image: choose your “over-sized items” category]

Comment: That seems to have worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @EcomTrav glad to hear. Be sure to [mark the answer as Accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).